# jQuery slider pagination: Adding callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YHMDN/. It's a slider pagination concept and I want it to display text parts instead of numbers, but having numbers maintained displayed in the slider to refer to different text parts (with perhaps a callback function) and having a scrollbar prompted. Who can help me out?

```
$(function() {

                var $update = $( '#preview > span' );

                $( "#slider" ).pagination( {
                    total : 100,
                    onChange : function( value ) {
                        $update.text( value );
                    }
                } );

            });
```

The pagination script github page: https://github.com/codrops/SliderPagination/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

$update.text($($('nav').find('a')[value-1]).text());

Comment: That worked, but if I fill in a additional value after the default one the numbering isn't corresponding with the new value given. I tried [value-2], but it didn't work. How to solve this?

Comment: Not sure I got what you're trying to do, Sir. Could you create another fiddle with your code and maybe explain in more details?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I placed an updated fiddle here: jsfiddle.net/YHMDN/1. As you can see when moving or clicking from the first to the second preview and than back to the first, the default one is 'Title 1' but than it becomes overwritten by the text I placed under the first paragraph. Also I inserted page breaks, but these don't seem to be displayed in the preview.